# Not display column if small value - Google Column Chart

Tags: graph, charts, google-visualization

My values are as below with a google column chart:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
 ['Year', 'Austria'],
 ['2003',  4000],
 ['2004',  1538156],
 ['2005',  1576579],
 ['2006',  1600652],
 ['2007',  19681137],
 ['2008',  1901067]
]);
```

My graph is displaying like as in below image:

[image]

I need to display that 4000 value in graph properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the column for 2003 is a sliver compared to the rest

when the vAxis starts at zero, the axis line and column are the same height
so the column doesn't show

you can use `getColumnRange` to the set `vAxis.viewWindow`

this will show the sliver (column), instead of the axis line

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Austria'],
      ['2003',  4000],
      ['2004',  1538156],
      ['2005',  1576579],
      ['2006',  1600652],
      ['2007',  19681137],
      ['2008',  1901067]
    ]);

    var columnRange = data.getColumnRange(1);

    var options = {
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Cups',
      },
      height: 600,
      title: 'Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country',
      vAxis: {
        title: 'Year',
        viewWindow: {
          min: columnRange.min
        }
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Whitehat,
It's the best solution I really like it.
But there is not displaying the last line limit for ex. (20,000,000) because there is last value is 19681137.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use сonfiguration options `chartArea`

Comment: Hi Dmitry,

Thank you for reply.
I have tried with it But I'm failing at it.
Can you please help me for the same?